# HTML - tag with # in front

Tags: html, dom

I saw a weird tag in DOM when there is an `iframe` tag.

Let's say we have this HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <iframe src="https://stackoverflow.com/"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

DOM looks like this:

[image]

What exactly is that `#document` and where I can find more info about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **DOM Inspector** is indicating that your `<iframe>` is linking to and displaying an *external* document.

(Or an inline document, if you use the `srcdoc` attribute).

In summary, the `#document` flag is there to confirm that everything within the `<iframe>` is a self-contained document, separate from the parent document.

Comment: And that thing has a name?

Comment: According to MDN, it's the [_"the active document in the inline frame's nested browsing context"_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement).